# Apache reverse proxy gets redirection

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, reverse-proxy, redirect

I'm trying to set up Apache as a reverse proxy. Here is the essential part of its configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost 10.16.10.245:9443
Listen 10.16.10.245:9443

<VirtualHost 10.16.10.245:9443>
  ServerName proxy.lan:9443

  SSLEngine on
  ...

  TraceEnable off

  SSLProxyEngine on
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyVia full
  ProxyPass / http://localhost/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/
</VirtualHost>
```

Note, that the proxy is listening on a non standard port 9443. When I use a dummy page showing phpinfo as a backend everything works as expected. However the site I need to put behind the proxy is either too strictly or too poorly written, so the behaivior changes like this:

```
client -> https://proxy.lan:443 -> http://localhost = success
client -> https://proxy.lan:<ANY_OTHER_PORT> -> http://localhost = wrong redirect
```

The client gets redirected from https://proxy.lan:9443/ to https://proxy.lan/auth/login and obviously proxy can't serve the request cause it doesn't listen on port 443:

```
# wget --no-check-certificate -vS https://proxy.lan:9443
--2019-05-12 02:51:37--  https://proxy.lan:9443/
Resolving proxy.lan (proxy.lan)... 10.10.254.186
Connecting to proxy.lan (proxy.lan)|10.10.254.186|:9443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify proxy.lan's certificate, issued by '...':
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
    WARNING: certificate common name 'backend.lan' doesn't match requested host name 'proxy.lan'.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  Date: Sat, 11 May 2019 23:51:37 GMT
  Server: Apache
  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
  Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
  Pragma: no-cache
  Location: https://proxy.lan/auth/login
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
  Content-Security-Policy: default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
  X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
  Content-Length: 0
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=...; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
  Via: 1.1 proxy.lan:9443 (Apache/2.2.31)
  Connection: close
Location: https://proxy.lan/auth/login [following]
--2019-05-12 02:51:37--  https://proxy.lan/auth/login
Connecting to proxy.lan (proxy.lan)|10.10.254.186|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Resolving proxy.lan (proxy.lan)... 10.10.254.186
Connecting to proxy.lan (proxy.lan)|10.10.254.186|:443... failed: Connection refused.
```

I can manually add the port to the resulting URL and https://proxy.lan:9443/auth/login works except for all links on the page pointing to https://proxy.lan/...

Apache environment looks like this:

```
HTTP_HOST   proxy.lan:9443
HTTP_VIA    1.1 proxy.lan:9443 (Apache/2.2.31)
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR    10.100.0.30
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST   proxy.lan:9443
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER     proxy.lan
HTTP_CONNECTION     Keep-Alive
SERVER_SIGNATURE    <address>Apache Server at proxy.lan Port 9443</address>
SERVER_NAME     proxy.lan
SERVER_ADDR     ::1
SERVER_PORT     9443
REMOTE_ADDR     ::1
...
```

Any ideas what can be done on the proxy side? Some rewrite rules maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ProxyPreserveHost on` is causing this. If you are not sure-sure that you need it, always leave it at default `off` and you are good.

For the rare cases when you do need `ProxyPreserveHost on`, adjust your   `ProxyPassReverse` wisely - this is the only directive that handles the redirects.

`ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/` looks wrong in your scenario, because your backend (the 80 app) doesn't seem to say "I redirect you to http://localhost/foo/bar" anywhere. If you put `ProxyPassReverse / https://proxy.lan/` there is a chance it will work better - check the official docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kubanczyk. Your version of ProxyPassReverse helped me to set the port right, although I can't say I understand clearly why it works. As for ProxyPreserveHost directive, it still set to on. In case it's off I get redirect to http://localhost/auth/login/. I also installed mod_proxy_html to remap paths in resulting page `ProxyHTMLEnable On; ProxyHTMLURLMap https://proxy.lan/ https://proxy.lan:9443/` and that concludes my setup.

Comment: I think if you use `curl -v http://localhost` and pay attention to the `Host:` header and the `Location:` header, you'll understand what the `ProxyPassReverse` does. It's a simple textual replacement. @FmyOen

Comment: Can you also explain the idea behind `ProxyPreserveHost Off`? Currently it looks for me like a total no-go, at least without applying some rewrite rules.

Comment: The idea is to behave as a normal http client, i.e. use header `Host: localhost` when talking to url `http://localhost/`